# Multilevel menu in Laravel Voyager admin panel not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, voyager

I am using Voyager admin package in my Laravel app. I tried to make 2 level dropdown menu like this:

```
Pages

  -page1

  -page2

    -page2A

    -page2B
```

but it seems that Voyager does not support 2 or more than 2 level menu dropdown. 
So I searched on the internet and I found only one solution for this on GitHub.[This one](https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/issues/2037)
I  tried to make a change like the above solution but it still it does not work. 
Anybody had this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Voyager boostrap menu:

`{{ menu('main_menu', 'bootstrap') }}`

work's only for 2 levels, if you need to go 3 levels deep you might use your own menu layout as mentioned here:

https://voyager.readme.io/docs/menus

you can find all menu layouts inside `vendor/tcg/voyager/resources/views/menu`

if you use the default one

```
{{ menu('main_menu', 'default') }}
```

It should work but without styling.

You can overwrite or create new menu inside `/resources/views/vendor/voyager/menu` however you call the file (for example my_custom.blade.php you can call that layout using `{{ menu('main_menu', 'my_custom') }}`